How to adjust door and which door locks should I install
I'm trying to find a way to adjust my park model home front door hinges so that way the door is more aligned with the frame. The door is catching on the bottom on the door strike side of the door. When I examined the hinges, it looks like the hinges are contained with the metal door frame itself. I've looked everywhere on Google and various forums, but I haven't found anything that explains park model door repairs.
Next, if I were to miraculously adjust the door in the frame, I would like to install a keypad deadbolt and lever door handle. Does anyone know of any products that I can install on the door which won't interfere with screen door?
Here's a link to the photos of the door.
https://imgur.com/a/0EW8cSt
Thanks for reading!

"Which door locks" is out of scope here; we don't do product recommendations. "What kinds of luck" would be in scope but usually boils down to "Spring latch knob set for convenience, deadbolt for security, both preferably gade 2 rather than the disposable grade three cheap-ass models, and if you're in a higher crime area home security is a larger topic covered in answers to past questions. "
